# Writing json into local file system

Tags: json, mongodb

In Mongodb I am having a test collection which holds a json document. I am able to retrieve the json and log it to my IDE console. Now I want to store this json into a file (i.e. test.json) on my local file system. I tried to create a code like this and however it is not working. There is some problem in line 4 because the file not able to write the cursor.

How do I get objects from mongodb to the file system, is there any sample code to be shared with me.

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();

FileWriter file = new FileWriter("D:\\test1.json");
while( cursor.hasNext() ) {
    file.write(cursor.toJSONString(); // this is line 4 
}
file.close();

System.out.println("JSON created successfully");
```

Comment: are you flushing before file close....file.flush();
  file.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;



public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        try {

            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dummyColl");

            // convert JSON to DBObject directly
            DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON
                    .parse("{'name':'mkyong', 'age':30}");

            collection.insert(dbObject);

            DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
            while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());
            }

            String st=JSON.serialize(cursorDoc);
            File file=new File("test.json");
            FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(st);
            fileWriter.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is missing (after `new` and before`write`):

```
file.open();
```